# How to split a sample based on a certain variable in Stata?

Tags: split, stata, using, sample

I need to split a sample into 4 groups of countries according to their GDP per capita. These thresholds are the 25th percentile, the 50th percentile and the 75th percentile. I am using Stata.

Comment: sum  GDPpercapita2,detail   , centile  gdppercapita2, c(25 50 75) but am not sure if i am correct

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
xtile group = GDPpercapita2, nq(4)
```

Comment: @ Dimitriy V. Masterov thanks ,the command works well but  please another question how can i single out a group (1,2,3,4) .So that i can work more on that  because i am interested in the lowest percentile that  is group 1

Comment: Add if group==1 to the end of whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks , please Using panel, how can I create a new variable i and variable j from an existing variable i.e if variablei  represent a country while the remaining represent countryj using stata

Comment: Please ask a new question in a new thread. You need to show attempts at code; if you aren't yet writing original code, you would be better off on Statalist.